# Find and display most recent referencing entities

Tags: 7, entities

I have 2 different node types. The first one describes a factory and the second one describes a measurement of the water inside the factory. The measurement content type has an Entity Reference field that points to the factory that the measurement is associated with.

What I want to do is print a list of all the factories in a table format and a specific column that will contain a field from the latest measurement that references to the specific factory.

For example:

## Factory 1

field 1
field 2
field 3

## Factory 2

field 1
field 2
field 3

### Measurement 1

Refers to Factory 1
Integer Field
Date Created: 21/5/2013

### Measurement 2

Refers to Factory 1
Integer Field
Date Created: 22/5/2013

### Measurement 3

Refers to Factory 2
Integer Field
Date Created: 10/2/2012

### Measurement 4

Refers to Factory 1
Integer Field
Date Created: 23/5/2013

**What I want to print**:
    Factory 1 || field 1 || field 2 || field 3 || Integer Field (from Measurement 4)
    Factory 2 || field 1 || field 2 || field 3 || Integer Field (from Measurement 3)

Notice that I'm only printing the Integer field from Measurement 4 since it is the latest measurement for the specific factory. I started writing some custom code and looked into EntityFieldQuery but I can't understand how to use it in conjunction with Entity Reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made an assumption about the way you want the table to be formatted, but something like the following should get you most of the way there:

```
// Set up the table.
$header = array('Factory Name', 'Field Value');
$rows = array();

// Get some nids for the factories you're interested in. Your real query will probably be more specific (checking status etc).
$args = array(':type' => 'factory');
$factory_nids = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type', $args)->fetchCol();

// Load the factory nodes.
$factory_nodes = node_load_multiple($factory_nids);

foreach ($factory_nodes as $factory_node) {
  // Add the factory name to the first column of this row.
  $row = array($factory_node->title);

  // Get the latest measurement related to this factory with an EntityFieldQuery.
  // fieldCondition() and fieldOrderBy()/propertyOrderBy() are the important bits here.
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'measurement')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    // This is the entity reference condition; entity ref fields use 'target_id' as the field column name.
    ->fieldCondition('field_factory_reference', 'target_id', $factory_node->nid)
    // If the date you're interested in is in a field, use something like this...
    ->fieldOrderBy('field_measurement_date', 'value', 'DESC')
    // ...or if you're interested in the node created date, this
    ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, 1);

  $results = $query->execute();

  // Make sure there are some results.
  if (!empty($results['node'])) {
    // EntityFieldQuerys always return an array of nids even if there's only one result, 
    // so it's easier to run through node_load_multiple and shift the element later
    $measurement_nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));

    // Get the node
    $latest_measurement_node = array_shift($measurement_nodes);

    if ($field_items = field_get_items('node', $latest_measurement_node, 'field_some_field')) {
      // If we have an appropriate value, add it to the row.
      $row[] = $field_items[0]['value'];
    }
    else {
      $row[] = 'No data found';
    }
  }
  else {
    $row[] = 'No data found';
  }

  $rows[] = $row;
}

$rendered_table = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module? Specifically:

Create a content view (i.e. latest_measurement_view):

1. Add the entity reference relationship which points the measurement type to the factory type
2. Add a contextual filter Content nid **with the above relationship**
3. Add a filter for the measurement content type
4. Add the integer field which belongs to the above type
5. Sort the view by post date descending
6. Set "Display a specific number of items" to 1 in the pager section

So this view gives you a single (integer) field that of the most recent measurement node for every corresponding factory node.

Now install and enable the [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module and create another content view (lets say factories_view) to list your factories in a table and:

1. Add a filter for the factory content type
2. Add a field of content nid and hide it from display
3. Add the fields you need from the factory type (title, fields 1, 2, 3 etc)
4. Add a global view field. In the window that pops up choose the latest_measurement_view and the display you want from the "Views Settings" section and finally (and most importantly) in the "Contextual Filters field" use the [!nid] token (replacement patterns: [!nid] == Content: Nid (raw))

Just be careful to always have the global view field after the content nid field.

You should now have the desired view result showing a table with the factories and a column displaying the integer field of the latest measurement next to each respective factory.